# Android Studio displays error on opening Android Emulator

Tags: android

I am getting error while running my code on Android Emulator. The emulator is opening but it does not display anything and android studio shows this error (given below). Please help.

**Error:**

```
C:\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_23
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:996
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: HAXM does not have enough memory remaining to load this AVD.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 1024 MB (for all running AVDs)
emulator: Try creating an AVD that requires less RAM or re-running the HAXM installer to set a higher memory limit. The HAXM installer may be found at C:\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe.
emulator: Failed to get Hax capability:6
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
```

**Emulator**
[image]

Comment: Did you tried do what this message says?

Comment: `HAXM does not have enough memory remaining to load this AVD. Try creating an AVD that requires less RAM or re-running the HAXM installer to set a higher memory limit.` What is confusing about this perfect description of the error and what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> emulator: HAXM does not have enough memory remaining to load this AVD.
>
> emulator: **AVD RAM size** = `1536 MB` emulator: **HAXM max RAM size** =
> `1024 MB` (for all running AVDs)

Probably, You'll need to set `AVD RAM size` `<= 1024`.